# Android Lock security to create password for a App

Tags: android, security, passwords, locking

I creating a demo app, where user need to set password (and can change it later times) to access app features. I can create a layout with password fields for user to create password. But, I would like to use/extend android's phone lock security feature instead of creating a new one. Is there any example/approach to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use device's default lock screen for your app but you can create a lock pattern for your app; Take a look at: http://haibison.github.io/android-lockpattern/